# How to retrieve recapthca answer of a challenge instead of getting only success status

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

I was trying to get an answer from the recaptcha instead of getting just successful/failed message but failed to get a way . 
To get the hold of the scenario lets assume one.

I got an recaptcha by firing this line in my php page :

```
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
```

Then i got a challenge.

[image: recpatha challenge]

Now when user submits it , this code is get executed.

```
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
```

This function definitions is :

```
function recaptcha_check_answer ($privkey, $remoteip, $challenge, $response, $extra_params = array())
```

**Now , what is $extra_params ? Where i can get to know about that. Nothing is stated in [recapthca api of php](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php). Is there any option to get the text of the recaptcha by passing something in  "$extra_params"?**

And when it is submitted, it sends me this response :

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2012 18:49:51 GMT Content-Type: text/plain X-Recaptcha-Request-Duration: 8 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Connection: close [1] => true success ) You got it!
```

**Now , i want to get the *answer of the recaptcha* in the response. In this specific challange this will be *"reign eveloost"***

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: An important question here - Why? Putting that aside for a second, you can get the user's submission from one of the two `$_POST` variables you are passing to `recaptcha_check_answer()` (off the top of my head I forget which, just echo them out) and if you get a `success` message back, you have the answer. Google do not publish information about what the additional parameters you can pass are, so I suspect they don't want you to mess about with them. They are probably only there to allow them to debug their own application.

Comment: @Dave Actually i want to run an OCR with the recaptcha challenge and check if it meets with the answer with the google's one. May be i can pass the decoded string with my OCR as the forms input value but the problem is i would like to measure a success percentage of my OCR algortihm.
By the way , are you sure about this : "Google do not publish information about what the additional parameters you can pass are" ???
By the way ,thanks for your information

Comment: The whole point of recaptcha is that is un-OCR-able. One of the words shown (`reign` above) could not be matched by an OCR algorithm that I'm willing to bet is better than yours (no offence) and the other (`eveloost`) is a known word that is purposefully scrambled to prevent OCR. Moreover, captchas in general are supposed to be impossible to read with OCR. If you want to test your OCR algorithm, you would do much better designing your own test cases, or do what source data for recaptcha does, and try and read a book.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation and after a long research on this , i also agree with you that it is a bad idea.

Comment: It was also my understanding that in many cases, one of the two words in the CAPTCHA is even unknown to Google which is why the serve it (and it can be typed slightly incorrectly and still be accepted).  Once many, many solutions have been submitted, they weigh them to see which was submitted the most and then figure that the users identified the unknown word for them.  This is so they can create searchable texts from the books/writings the words came from in the first place.

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob Would you mind contacting me via contact form on the URL found in my info bio in my SO profile?  Perhaps we can work together on something and help each other out in the process.

Comment: @drew did not find any contact info from your profile. can you provide any other option please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lots of googling and research effort , i found out that the way recaptcha works , it is not possible to get answer . I can only mange to know a success status .That's all.

Answer (score 1):

reCAPTCHA does not have a method for returning the actual challenge that was presented to the user. The reason is because of security. I personally think reCAPTCHA is a great concept, but it's one of the most annoying things in the world since half the time, you cannot read the challenge. I find myself clicking the "new challenge" button more than 10 times.

Either way, if you want to do what you have mentioned, you would be better off using a self-hosted CAPTCHA solution.

Also the `$extra_params` variable is to include additional parameters to the call. Google does not mention that it allows extra params, so in my best understanding, it was added in case Google implements new parameters to the API in the future that is not included in the library now. It would make it more simple for people using older versions of the library.